# LNK1181: cannot open input file 'FlyCapture2_v140.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to build a simple exemple in c++ using Visual Studio 2015 that comes with the sdk kit of the [PointGrey GigECam BlackFly](https://www.ptgrey.com/blackfly-gige-poe-cameras). However i'm getting this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'FlyCapture2_v140.lib'
```

The original project is written using Visual Studio 2012, this problem that could being caused because i'm using a different version of the VS?

Comment: You will get problems with different version of VS, however this is not the cause of your current problem.  Either the library name is not spelt correctly or you have not given the correct library include path.

Comment: Other possibilities are `FlyCapture2_v140.lib` is corrupt or you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.